# Update select contents without reloading form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have quite a long form which has many HTML form selects pulling data from MySQL tables - quite often a client will be mid way through filling in the form when they realise that the value they want for department, for example, has not yet been entered into the system so is not in the list.

I have added a link to a simplified popup for adding departments but after it is added it does not appear in the select list as the contents of that select are based on what was available on the load of the page when the initial query ran - how can I get the select to update without having to submit and then edit, without the page refreshing/reloading and without the client losing the data they have currently added?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did read what you are asking, since its too long) But did you try javascript? changing form values after paged loaded is possible only with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

When submit form on that popup, save it with ajax in database, and as response get inserted data... Then on ajax success add new option in select ( with returned data )